# Subscribing to a removed queue with spring-websocket and RabbitMQ broker (Queue NOT_FOUND)

Tags: spring, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a spring-websocket (4.1.6) application on Tomcat8 that uses a STOMP RabbitMQ (3.4.4) message broker for messaging. When a client (Chrome 47) starts the application, it subscribes to an endpoint creating a durable queue. When this client unsubscribes from the endpoint, the queue will be cleaned up by RabbitMQ after 30 seconds as defined in a custom made RabbitMQ policy. When I try to reconnect to an endpoint that has a queue that was cleaned up, I receive the following exception in the RabbitMQ logs: "NOT_FOUND - no queue 'position-updates-user9zm_szz9' in vhost '/'\n". I don't want to use an auto-delete queue since I have some reconnect logic in case the websocket connection dies.

This problem can be reproduced by adding the following code to the [spring-websocket-portfolio](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) github example.

In the container div in the index.html add:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="appModel.subscribe()">SUBSCRIBE</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="appModel.unsubscribe()">UNSUBSCRIBE</button>
```

In portfolio.js replace:

```
stompClient.subscribe("/user/queue/position-updates", function(message) {
```

with:

```
positionUpdates = stompClient.subscribe("/user/queue/position-updates", function(message) {
```

and also add the following:

```
  self.unsubscribe = function() {
    positionUpdates.unsubscribe();
  }

  self.subscribe = function() {
    positionUpdates = stompClient.subscribe("/user/queue/position-updates", function(message) {
      self.pushNotification("Position update " + message.body);
      self.portfolio().updatePosition(JSON.parse(message.body));
    });
  }
```

Now you can reproduce the problem by:

1. Launch the application
2. click unsubscribe
3. delete the position-updates queue in the RabbitMQ console
4. click subscribe

Find the error message in the websocket frame via the chrome devtools and in the RabbitMQ logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Stomp won't recreate the queue if it get's deleted by the RabbitMQ policy. I worked around it by creating the queue myself when the SessionSubscribeEvent is fired.

```
public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractSubProtocolEvent event) {
   if (event instanceof SessionSubscribeEvent) {
      MultiValueMap nativeHeaders = (MultiValueMap)event.getMessage().getHeaders().get("nativeHeaders");
      List destination = (List)nativeHeaders.get("destination");
      String queueName = ((String)destination.get(0)).substring("/queue/".length());

      try {
         Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
         Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
         channel.queueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> reconnect logic in case the websocket connection dies.

and

> no queue 'position-updates-user9zm_szz9' in vhost

Are fully different stories.

I'd suggest you implement "re-subscribe" logic in case of deleted queue.

Actually that is how STOMP works: it creates `auto-deleted` (generated) queue for the subscribe and yes, it is removed on the unsubscrire.

See more info in the RabbitMQ STOMP Adapter [Manual](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html).

From other side consider to subscribe to the existing AMQP queue:

> To address existing queues created outside the STOMP adapter, destinations of the form `/amq/queue/<name>` can be used.

Comment: So if I understood correct this is a pure Stomp issue. If you subscribe to "/queue/xyz" for the first time, Stomp creates a durable queue. If you unsubscribe and remove the generated queue, Stomp doesn't know that the queue was deleted (outside its session). So if you subscribe again you'll get the error. (Too bad Stomp doesn't just recreate the queue though) I guess I'll work around this by managing the creation of the queues myself outside Stomp. Because I don't want to use auto-delete queues, since I want to be able to reconnect to the queue without losing messages after a tcp failure.